# kendo grid column with image and text

Tags: kendo-ui

I have grid which looks like the image below and in the Description column I have a notepad icon, when I click that image I need a pop up to be displayed with value of description column so that I can edit, save and close it.

I used the following code:

```
<div id="viewSCtable" style="width: 75%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var UserGroup = [{
                UserGroupName: "Guest",
                Status: "Active",
                NoOfUsers: 4,
                CreatedDate: "2013-04-24T00:00:00",
                Description: "Can be used  by Guest for"
            }, {
                UserGroupName: "Exportor",
                Status: "Active",
                NoOfUsers: 4,
                CreatedDate: "2013-04-24T00:00:00",
                Description: "Can be used  by Guest for"

            }, {
                UserGroupName: "Sales",
                Status: "Active",
                NoOfUsers: 4,
                CreatedDate: "2013-04-24T00:00:00",
                Description: "Can be used  by Guest for"

            }];
            function getUserGroup() {
                return UserGroup;
            }

            var element = $("#viewSCtable").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: getUserGroup(),
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                UserGroupName: { type: "string" },
                                Status: { type: "string" },
                                NoOfUsers: { type: "number" },
                                CreatedDate: { type: "string" },
                                Description: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                dataBound: function () {
                },
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: {
                    mode: "multiple",
                    allowUnsort: true
                },
                reorderable: true,
                refreshable: true,
                resizable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false,
                    pageSizes: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                //filterable: {
                //    extra: false,
                //    operators: {
                //        string: {
                //            startswith: "Starts with",
                //            contains: "Contains"
                //        }
                //    }
                //},

                columns: [
                    { field: "UserGroupName", title: "User Group Name", width: "12%", attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" } },
                    { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "10%", attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" } },
                    { field: "Description", title: "Description", width: "25%", attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },
                    template: '<span>#: Description #<img src="../../images/notepad.png" title="Edit Description" style="float:right;width:9%;cursor: pointer;" onclick="onEdit(this.row)"/></span>'
                    },
                    { field: "NoOfUsers", title: "No of Users", width: "10%" },
                    { command: [{ name: "destroy", width: "1%", template: "<a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='deleteRow(this)' title='Edit'>Edit</a> / <a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='deleteRow(this)' title='Delete'>Delete</a>" }], title: "Action" },
                ],
            });
        });

        function deleteRow(element) {
            grid = $("#viewSCtable").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.removeRow($(element).closest("tr"));
        }
        function onEdit(e) {

            var selected = grid.select();
            if (selected && selected.length > 0) {
                $.each(selected, function (idx, elem) {
                    grid.editRow(grid.select());
                });
            }
        }

</script>
```

[image: Current Grid]

Comment: As far as I see in the code there are two different edits: the link and the notepad icon. I understand that you want just to edit description when clicked on notepad, correct?... What about when you click on edit link everything or everything else? Why having two editions modes?

Comment: yes you are corrct. and clicking on the Edit button it will redirect to another page

Comment: Actually I've asked several questions so "you are correct" is not an answer to all of them. I still cannot get what are you exactly trying to do and the final "and clicking on the Edit button it will redirect to another page" introduces more doubts.